# FirebaseMessaging.configure doesn't run when app is in background while notification is received

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

configure method from an instance of FirebaseMessaging doesn't run when app is in background while notification is received.

```
class MainMenuState extends State<MainMenuPage> {
  final FirebaseMessaging _messaging = FirebaseMessaging();

  int counter = 1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _messaging.getToken().then((token){
    print(token);
  });

  _messaging.configure(

    onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
      print("A notification was received. But this onMessage won't run when app is in background.");
      postCall(message['notification']['title'], message['notification']['body']);
    },
    onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
      print("onResume will run when a notification is pressed, resuming an app in background.");
      postCall(message['data']['title'], message['data']['body']);
    },
    onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
      print('on launch $message');
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Don't post pictures of code please. Replace it with the actual code as text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Comment: Please add a bit more details. No idea what your problem is - "doesn't really execute", what is an non-real execution? What do you expect to see? What do you see? What have you tried? iOS or Android? Why do you expect your application to call `configure` in the background? What triggers that `configure` call?

Comment: solutions then? am also facing the same issue